# Why multiple commands in yargs are not working?

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, yargs

I am working on a CLI Project, where the user has to login before using any of its other commands.
Below are the commands that the user will interact with.

1. oms login -u *username* -p -a *auth_url*
2. oms get -u *url*

When I'm trying to see the help for **oms login** , it is showing help for the **oms get** command.

```
const argv = require('yargs/yargs')(process.argv.slice(2))
    .usage('Usage: $0 <command> [options]')
    .command({
        command: "oms login",
        desc: "Login the User to OMS",
        builder: {
            username: {
                alias: 'u',
                demandOption: true

            },
            password: {
                alias: 'p',
                demandOption: true
            },
            auth_url: {
                alias: 'a',
                demandOption: true
            }
        },
        handler: (argv) => console.log(argv),
    })
    .command({
        command: "oms get",
        desc: "Get the Status",
        builder: {
            url: {
                alias: 'u',
                demandOption: true
            }
        },
        handler: (argv) => console.log(argv),
    })
    .help('h')
    .alias('h', 'help')
    .wrap(null)
    .argv;
```

Help from **oms login**

```
PS F:\node\REST-CLI\cli> node .\index.js oms login --help
index.js oms get

Get the Status

Options:
      --version  Show version number  [boolean]
  -h, --help     Show help  [boolean]
  -u, --url  [required]
```

Help from **oms get**

```
PS F:\node\REST-CLI\cli> node .\index.js oms get --help
index.js oms get

Get the Status

Options:
      --version  Show version number  [boolean]
  -h, --help     Show help  [boolean]
  -u, --url  [required]
```

I'm using above code, Kindly let me know me where I'm doing the mistake.
Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing it's because command names can't have spaces in them. If you want sub-commands you have to make a oms command, and then in the handler for that you want to define the commands `get` and `login`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that `index.js` would be your executable that you can put into `package.json` as

```
  "bin": {
    "oms": "./index.js"
  },
```

Then you define subcommands as:

```
    .command({
        command: "login",
        // 
    })
    .command({
        command: "get",
        // rest ommited

    })
```